# Android SQLite and Multiple Packages

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

So i went to update a previous app i created (FULLY FUNCTIONAL) and now when i try accessing the database I see this error below (the tag doesn't indicate its from my app I believe it is). The only real changes I've made is to create multiple packages for better organization but i left the original package and the provider in that package... Any idea's?

```
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813): Writing exception to parcel
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14620)
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2258)
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:663)
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
05-27 08:04:50.841: E/DatabaseUtils(813):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons for this. Have you checked your manifest? Sometimes this issue is caused by duplicate or incorrect entries, e.g. an activity tag, with the wrong location. Sounds like that's a possibility here; you may have created new packages but never updates activity/class tags that were keyed to those locations. Other edits are possible but usually its in the manifest not the java code.

Comment: clear the project and rebuild it again.

Comment: I cleaned the project with no success, I went through the manifest but since most of the screens are fragments there wasn't much in it...

Comment: Wait spoke too soon its working!